# Android: One ViewModel for multiple Fragments possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have a general question about App architecture with Android. I am implementing an App (in Java) that has a single activity and 20Fragments (that are similar but not the same). So far I implemented everything in the fragments (UI, Logic, Database queries). Now I am considering to use a ViewModel but I am not sure whether it is worth the effort. So my question is whether each of my 20 Fragments should have an own ViewModel or whether I can just implement one ViewModel for all the 20 Fragments? Implementing a ViewModel for all Fragment classes would drastically increase the effort, so I would like to know if it is possible to have only one ViewModel for all Fragments?

Comment: Could you please clear that you want a ViewModel class with single instance for all fragments or each fragment will create its object??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is technically possible to have one `ViewModel` for all `Fragment`s.

However, since this one `ViewModel` would have to manage a number of very different use cases, it would be something like a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). With 20 Fragments, it would have very many lines of code ...

Switching over to MVVM is generally worth the effort becasue in the long run the app is easier to test and to maintain.

It may be a good idea to have a `BaseViewModel` in your app: a `ViewModel` class which handles things which are similar in all use cases, like letting the `Fragment` know that it should show a loading indicator or an error message. The "normal" `ViewModel`s could extend `BaseViewModel` and focus on their use cases.

It makes sense in some cases to have a shared `ViewModel`, for example when a `Fragment` shows a dialog with some `EditText`s or when one has workflow with a sequence of 3-4 `Fragment`s on a small device where on a larger device one or two `Fragment`s would suffice.

Just in case, here's my favourite starting point for MVVM app architecture: [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide)

Comment: Thanks Bö macht Blau for your answer (I upvoted it). Thanks for the link. Unfortunately there they only explain how to do this in Kotlin (which I don't use). Do you have a link where it is also explained in Java? Further, would I also need a separate Database class for every Fragment? I think one option is to have just one Database class for all queries that uses static methods. Anyways, for me the effort implementing 20 ViewModels seems to be too high and not worth to be totally honest.

Comment: @VanessaF - since Kotlin has been the preferred language for some years now, finding sample code in Java is becoming difficult :(  Maybe [this link](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/BasicSample) will help. AFAIK one uses a  singleton database regardless of whether one works with ViewModels or not

Comment: I can very much understand that refactoring most of your code does not seem worth the effort. But maybe you can find a compromise: every time you have to change a specific Fragment anyway, you migrate it to MVVM architecture. The decision what is best for your app depends on what your app does, so in the end you're the one who knows best :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and effort Bö macht Blau. I really appreciate it. I have some questions and comments to your comments. 1) What do you mean by "one uses a singleton database"? Just to use one static database class for all fragments. 2) My Fragments have a lot of elements in them. So I guess the effort even for one Fragment to change it to the MVVM architecture is quite high and I would also have to use MutableLiveData. Do I have to integrate everything into the ViewModel from the UI?

Comment: @VanessaF - 1) By "singleton" I meant one database for the whole application. It  depends on the implementation whether one has a single instance of the database class e.g. with a static `getInstance()` method or even an instance provided by dependency injection

Comment: Thanks Bö for your comment and effort. But as far as I understand you posted link from the answer https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide every Fragment has its own database or at least a model. And every Fragment should have a Webservice or at least a Remote Data Source. So should every Fragment have its own class for handling the database operations?

Comment: 2) Usually there is data which one wants to present to the user and data which the user can enter. I usually like to expose the first type of data via LiveData and route the second type of data to the ViewModel which then decides to maybe update its LiveData or to save everything. I once read something about ["Passive View"](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html)  by Martin Fowler - at first I was a little bit skeptical but today I try to build my apps that way

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bö. You wrote " I usually like to expose the first type of data via LiveData and route the second type of data to the ViewModel which then decides to maybe update its LiveData or to save everything". I have  to admit that I don't understand this at all. So the data that is presented to the user should be LiveData? What if the data never changes within one Fragment creation (it only changes when the Fragment is created again). What use is it then to use LiveData? And the second type of data is given to the ViewModel. Bu what does it do with it and why.

Comment: @VanessaF - If you use MVVM, the Fragment will never access the database on its own. Each Fragment talks to its ViewModel which in turn talks to the repository which has access to local or remote datasources. In the "guide" it says there should be one "source of truth". For me, that's the repository.

Comment: The ViewModel should expose (make accessible) data to the Fragment as LiveData. The Fragment observes the LiveData and updates its Views accordingly. You are correct, if the data does never change, LiveData look like overkill. But at least if it has to be loaded from some server, the Fragment can observe the corresponding LiveData, and as soon as the data is loaded the Fragment will receive it. If the users decide to quit before the loading has finished, no problem. Without LiveData, one always had to check on success whether `getView() != 0` ...

Comment: If I have a master-and-detail App (like a TODO list with a detail screen for a specific TODO), one repository with two methods getTodos() and getTodo(int todoId) may do. It might have just one remote endpoint and/ or just one database query (SELECT *) for loading all TODOs, and the repository could provide both ViewModels with the required data by either passing along the whole list or just one specific list item.

Comment: Thanks Bö for your answer. I accepted it (and I had upvoted it before). The ViewModel thing seems to be more complex than I anticipated and furthermore you have to write a lot of additional code. Due to the fact that I would have to do this for more than 20 Fragments I think that I will stick to my approach and just put everything inside the fragment. Thus the amount of code is reduced as I do not need any further Java classes. But thanks for your answer and comments. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Have one view model for each fragment. This way each viewmodel is responsible for doing something related to one fragment and so testing is also easier.

In fact you can have multiple view models for a single fragments doing different things for you.

Keeping everything in one view model would make testing harder and also you have to keep viewmodel for all 20 fragments may be scoping to activity.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I am considering to use a ViewModel but I am not sure whether it
> is worth the effor

This is definitely worth it if you want good for future development.

> So my question is whether each of my 20 Fragments should have an own
> ViewModel or whether I can just implement one ViewModel for all the 20
> Fragments?

Each fragment should have its own ViewModel, I don't appreciate sharing ViewModel. I develop a lot of apps and what I've come to realize is that I should try to avoid tight coupling. Because every time you develop there will be a lot of changes and when you edit or add or remove it will make you edit a lot because the links are too tight. It would be nice to take them apart and still be able to run normally and when needed to be able to reassemble them like putting together puzzle pieces.

> Implementing a ViewModel for all Fragment classes would drastically
> increase the effort, so I would like to know if it is possible to have
> only one ViewModel for all Fragments?

possible if you want, in programming nothing is impossible. But if you do, you shouldn't because it will only make your code more complicated.

You can read more about the model here.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#overview

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nhan (I upvoted it). When I have one ViewModel for every Fragment I think the effort is way too high. Furthermore, the app structure becomes more complex as I would have many classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through with this link
[Shareable ViewModel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THt9QISnIMQ)

This is pretty much easy with Kotlin by using extention function, But In Java, we need to create a function for creating ViewModel and handle their scope according to the lifecycle of activity/fragment.